# Очередь на C++

Tags: c++builder, ооп, c++

Каким образом можно организовать очередь в С++ Builder? Нужно закидывать туда значения типа  іnt, после чего в обратном порядке оттуда их доставать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ классический - использовать stl. Там есть готовые решения. Судя по описанию, нужен стек. В любом случае его можно организовать на деке.
Добавляем #include <deque>
теперь

```
std::deque<int> d;
d.push_back(1); // добавить с конца
d.push_front(2); // добавить с начала
int x = d.back(); // взять с конца, но не удалять
d.pop_back(); // и удалить 
int y = d.front(); // взять с начала
d.pop_front(); // и удалить
```

То есть, можно добавлять и удалять с нужно конца (деку лучше себе представить в виде трубы, с каждого конца можно добавлять и удалять). Больше - тут http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/

Comment: А чем вам std::stack не угодил?

Comment: я вначале думал написать о нем и о queue, но не уверен, стек или очередь нужна (не ручаюсь, что я правильно понимаю "доставать в обратном порядке"). К тому же stack - это адаптер обычно, на базе deque.